# Java mysql から情報をselect取得して　配列として返す方法

Tags: java

再びすみません

```
public class MemberCtrl {

    //変数を定義する
    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;


    public MemberCtrl(Connection con) {
        this.con=con;
    }

    public Member[] excuteSelect() throws SQLException {
         // ステートメント生成
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        // SQLを実行する
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM T_MEMBER";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        *// 結果行をループ
        while(rs.next()){
            // レコードの値
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            String email= rs.getString("email");
            //結果を表示する
            System.out.println("id:"+id+" "+"name:"+name+" "+"email:"+email);
        }
        return ;*　間違っています

    }
```

そして別のクラスで結果を出力する

```
public class Toi1_db {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws SQLException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection con =(new DBConnection()).getConnection();
        MemberCtrl memctrl = new MemberCtrl(con);
        Member[] mem = memctrl.excuteSelect();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < mem.length ; i++ ){
            //以下は出力処理

        }
    }
}
```

SQLを実行して、結果　配列Member[]　として返す方法はなんですか？
一つ目のコード　結果を配列として返す
二つ目のクラスで　出力処理を行う
どなたがお分かりですか？

Comment: すでにマイナス票が入れられているようですが、質問するにあたっては問題点を絞ってください。ソースも見やすく整形してください。`Member`クラスはどこに定義されていますか？ `while(rs.next())` が何をしているのか理解されていますか？ あとこちらも参考に。[良い質問をするには? - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

まず、public Member[] excuteSelect() メソッドがMemberクラスの配列を返すと宣言されていますね。

Toi1_dbクラスのmain()メソッドでも、MemberCtrlのexecuteSelectの実行結果を受け取るよう記載していますので、呼び出し方は問題ないようです。

問題となっているのは、データベースに対してSELECT文を実行した結果がResultSetに入っていますので、これを取得した件数分だけループして、Memberクラスに入れるところでしょうか。

nameとemailなど、ResultSetから１行の項目を取り出していますので、その内容をMemberに格納し、繰り返して取り出した結果をMemberの配列であるMember[]に入れて返す必要があります。

Member１つ１つを配列に格納しなければなりませんし、あらかじめ取得した件数分の配列を用意しなければいけないので、できれば動的に値を格納できるjava.util.ArrayListを使ってMemberを格納する方法が良いと思います。

なのでMember[]となっている箇所を、Listとするのが、まずは良いでしょう。

ちなみにですが、Memberクラスは、id,name,emailのフィールドはありますよね？

参考になれば幸いです。